# Ideas for table row outline on hover? CSS outline fails on tr in Webkit

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, z-index, outline

I'm trying to build a table (filled with actual tabular data), and get an outline effect for a row on hover.  I've tried a couple ideas, but cross-browser issues are holding me back.  Would love to hear any ideas.

**Idea #1**: Add CSS `outline` when hovering over <tr>.  Works in IE8 & FF3, but not IE7 or Chrome (Webkit, so probably Safari too).  The actual implementation of the hover is omitted for brevity:

```
<table style="margin:10px;width:800px">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="outline:red solid 3px">
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Idea #2**: Position a <div> under the <tr> that is wider/taller than the <tr>, and use `z-index` to stack the <div> below the <tr>, but on top of adjacent <tr>s.  This is much more interesting, because I can potentially do rounded corners, opacity, etc. This looked promising, but so do many ideas when implemented first in Firefox.  After reading up on `z-index` and playing around with code in several different browsers, I'm totally frustrated.  The stacking/ordering I'm trying here is maybe too complex to work in different browsers.

Example code using jquery-ui and Position (http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Position):

[non-working code link removed]

---

**EDIT**: Super awesome slightly kludgish solution below including opacity and rounded corners in all but IE.  I'll have to do a blog writeup one of these days on all the little issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made idea #2 work, which I think is pretty nifty.  Several tricks had to be used.  First, block elements had to be put inside `td` elements in order to get `z-index` working in several browsers.  I used `span` elements with `display:block` to fill the entire `td`, which means some `td` css properties will have to be put inside those `span` elements and further nested but not yet added `span` elements (borders and padding in particular).

I added some opacity and rounded corners (no rounded corners in IE).

Comment: Nice one. The `tr` doesn't have a border/outline property, so you really can't do anything with it.

Comment: Uhm, couldn't see the example working.  Tested on Chrome 18, IE9 and Firefox 12.

Perhaps because I'm from the future??

Comment: The link is dead. Any chance to get a new link?

Comment: Answers should not rely on external links

Answer (score 0):

2 sounds terribly complicated.  How about this:

```
tr:hover td{ outline: red solid 3px}
```

EDIT

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("tr").hover( 
 function(){ 
  $(this).css({"outline":"red solid 3px"}); 
 }, 
 function(){ 
  $(this).css({"outline":"red solid 0px"}); 
 }   
 ); 
 }); 
</script>
```

Whoops.. this still fails in webkit.

EDIT

OK, try again...

Webkit honours the TR OUTLINE *if* you give the TR "display:block", so, the following works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
table {

}
tr {
    outline-color: #f00;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-width: 0px;
    display: block
}
.thick {
    outline-width:3px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("td").hover(
       function(){
         $(this).parent().addClass("thick");
       },
       function(){
         $(this).parent().removeClass("thick");
       }  
       );
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="margin:10px;width:800px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 3</td>
            <td>Test 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But, I realise, this also fails in IE7. :(

Comment: 2 is where all the fun is though!  Haha...  I really want the outline to be outside of the row -- no vertical lines on the inside of the row.  It's too bad outline doesn't allow you to define each side like border.  A solution using borders instead will change the box model on hover which I want to stay away from.

Comment: Good try, however display:block changes the rendering of the table row to be in essence a block (like a div), so that its row-like properties are gone. We might as well build a table using non-table elements and css if we go this route.  I haven't ruled that out, but the data is definitely the kind I'd like to keep in actual html tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with after asking my own question on SO - [Outline table row on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128247/top-border-color-of-td-cell-is-hidden)

What you do is remove the bottom border for all of the td's with `bottom-border: 0`. The top borders of the other cells will keep everything looking the way they should, except for the last row. The last row we fix with `tr:last-child td { bottom-border: your border style }`. Finally in your hover pseudoclass you set the bottom border.

http://jsfiddle.net/S9pkM/16/

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; } /*I am aware of separate */
table td { border: 1px solid black; width: 50px; height: 25px; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 0; }
table tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
table tr:hover td { border-top-color: red; border-bottom: 1px solid red; }
table tr:hover td:first-child { border-left-color: red; }
table tr:hover td:last-child  { border-right-color: red; }
```