# Outline table row on hover

Tags: html, css, colors, border, css-tables

I am trying to highlight the border of a table row on hover. Unfortunately this only works for the first row of cells. Lower rows have one border that does not change color. I have tried using `outline` but it doesn't play nice with `:hover` in webkit.

http://jsfiddle.net/S9pkM/2/

Imagine your standard table html. Some tr's with some td's. Hovering over a row should highlight its border in red.

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; } /*I am aware of separate */
table td { border: 3px solid black; }
table tr:hover td { border-top-color: red; border-bottom-color: red; }
table tr:hover td:first-child { border-left-color: red; }
table tr:hover td:last-child  { border-right-color: red; }
```

I am open to alternate approaches, but I am stuck with the table structure. No inserting additional html besides standard `<table> <tr> <td>`

Comment: I think it is not because of :hover. It is how table behaves.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've been facing this same problem and finally found a simpler solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7942229/114029).

You can use this CSS trick ( `border-style: double;` ) that works for 1px borders:

```
#mytable tr.row:hover td
{
    border-style: double;
    border-color: red;
}
```

This will make your `border-color` work (be the top most one) no matter what. :-)

Comment: Nice, this is much simpler. I don't see a visual difference between double and solid. http://jsfiddle.net/emeGe/

Comment: Huh! Is this because `double` does some kind of new stacking order context creation? Or is it something far more sinister?

Comment: any suggestion for dashed border-style?

Comment: This works well enough, except that both FF and Chrome seem to have rendering bugs that occasionally leave the border box color on some of the border after the hover has ended. Mostly occurs on the last row and last column of the table. Never managed to workaround the rendering bugs.

Comment: I had to change the selector to `#mytable tr:hover td` for it to work, otherwise very nice!

Answer (score 6):

For 1px borders see Leniel's solution that uses `border-style: double`. This is much simpler. A double border is one that shows a 1px line for the inside and outside edges of the border. This doesn't do anything for a 1px border, but on >1px there is a gap.

For borders >1px you remove the bottom border for all of the `<td>`'s with `border-bottom: 0`. The top borders of the other cells will keep everything looking the way they should, except for the last row. The last row we fix with `tr:last-child td { border-bottom: your border style }`. Finally in your hover pseudoclass you set the bottom border.

http://jsfiddle.net/S9pkM/16/

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; } /*I am aware of separate */
table td { border: 1px solid black; width: 50px; height: 25px; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 0; }
table tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
table tr:hover td { border-top-color: red; border-bottom: 1px solid red; }
table tr:hover td:first-child { border-left-color: red; }
table tr:hover td:last-child  { border-right-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use separate border?
http://jsfiddle.net/S9pkM/6/

Comment: Because I am using 1px borders. That's why I said `I am aware of separate.` I also don't like the look of the different colored borders stacking on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code into your head section:

```
<style>
  table td { border: 2px solid transparent; width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;}
  table td:hover {border:2px solid red; }
</style>
```

Comment: This does not work. Notice that a border is missing on hover. http://jsfiddle.net/S9pkM/90/