# css outline always on first table row on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

on google chrome when you have outline on a table row you get it only on the first row

so using this css:

```
tr { 
      outline:1px solid red; 
   }
```

you'll get the outline only on the first row, you can see that if you open this link in chrome:

http://jsbin.com/enupey/27/edit

anybody knows any workaround/fix for this ?

Thank You

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81373, though if I recall correctly you shouldn't really rely on styling `tr` due to limitations in browsers for the styling of it.

Answer (score 5):

Though it appears to be a bug, a little googling and I found a working solution as part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957655/916299)

Adding:

```
display: block;
```

appears to work:

```
tr
{
  outline:1px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

The edited result can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/enupey/3/edit)

---

I fiddled around with the CSS a bit more and came up with this:

```
td
{
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  bottom-padding:-1px;
}

table
{
  border-left:2px solid red;
  border-right:2px solid red;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
  bottom-padding:-1px;
}
```

Would that be suitable?

Caveat: I did only test this on Google Chrome for Mac.

Comment: does work but it ruins the table layout (noticeable if you have a width for the table tag)

Comment: Edited answer. The main difference being I used borders instead of outlines.

Comment: adding `display:block` is enough as i tested

Answer (score 1):

The [`table` tag has a `rules` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_rules.asp) which allows you to define how where borders are "ruled" in the table. However, note that:

> The rules attribute is supported in all major browsers.
>
> Note: The rules attribute is not supported in IE, prior version 9.
>
> Note: Chrome and Safari displays this attribute incorrectly: They add
>   the affected outside borders in addition to the inside borders.

Combining this with the [frame attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_frame.asp) and the CSS from your original question, this provides boxed outlines on each row:

```
<table rules="rows" frame="box">
```

[image: Outcome]

You can see this amendment to JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/enupey/13/edit)

(Tested on Mac Chrome)

(I've added this as a separate answer because my previous answer concentrates on CSS, this solution, using only HTML seems distinct enough to separate the answers)

Comment: According the [table page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table), the `rules` attribute is deprecated. Also, see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: That first page also says not to use the <table> tag, but the question features it.

Comment: As the page states, the use of the `TABLE` tag for the purpose of layout is discouraged. In semantic HTML theory, tables are for the purpose of displaying tabular data (numbers, figures), and using them for that reason is perfectly fine/encouraged. The question doesn't explicitly state whether the purpose is for tabular data or not, _but_ the `rules` attribute is still deprecated.

Comment: -1 for referencing w3schools (not actually going to vote down, though)

Comment: I didn't realise w3s was considered unreliable. Is MDN a more reliable source for all browsers?

Comment: @JamesWebster MDN is one of the best documentation places in the WWW and is considered by most ppl as the best free online documentation for javascript that exists (I believe that also applies for the rest of the articles it has)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect answer for a few reasons, but I'm tossing it out there as an option… Set `border-collapse: collapse;` on the `TABLE` element, and style borders around every row's `TD` and `TH` elements. See [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/enupey/16/edit) for the final output. Because it relies on `border-collapse` it won't work without the additional `cellspacing` HTML attribute in IE6/7. It also might not give the same effect you're looking for, if you're looking to outline each row individually. The solution also depends on the use of the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-selectors, and IE8 doesn't support `:last-child`. This can be worked around by adding "first" and "last" as classes on certain elements, but that's less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

With `display: block` you could do:

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ads</td>
    <td>azx</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='sel'>
    <td>ads</td>
    <td>azx</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ads</td>
    <td>azx</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr
{
display: block;
}

tr.sel
{
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

And the output is: http://jsbin.com/enupey/79/edit

Answer (score 0):

This works as demonstrated [**here**](http://jsbin.com/enupey/17/edit), without, I believe, any major side-effects:

```
tr
{
  display: table-row-group;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code like below.

The Html code for table is

```
<table rules='none'>

</table>
```

and change the css with

```
tr.sel
{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

It will render the border on the middle raw in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Fix to your problem : Change your CSS to.

```
tr
{
  outline:1px solid red;
  display:inherit;
}
```

OR

```
  tr
   {
     outline:1px solid red;
     display:block;
   }
```

If you are `concerned with table layout` then you have to fight with the spaces by setting `margin` to some negative value. see here :

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

A bug has already been reported follow up link : http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81373&q=outline&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: display:inherit or block ruins the layout

Answer (score -1):

ya, its a bug

try border instead of outline, and give table style `border-collapse:collapse`

no change in html, css now

```
tr.sel
{
  border:1px solid red; 

}
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Demo

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUVCe/) , [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/enupey/78/edit)

Comment: what if I aleady use border, and I want outline around it